# Is it possible to imply a class properties type based on another properties value?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to type a class or it's properties in a way that the type of one property can be implied by the value of another?

As can be seen with the `testWithTyping` method that uses the `MyType` type.

The end goal is to be able to tell a class that if property `x` is `true` then property `y` has a value.

**Example code:**

```js
type MyType = { isSet: false, id: null } | { isSet: true, id: number };

class MyClass {
  isSet: boolean = false;
  id: number | null = null;

  constructor(id?: number) {
    if (typeof id === 'number' && id > 0) {
      this.isSet = true;
      this.id = id;
    }
  }

  test() {
    if (this.isSet) {
      this.logId(this.id); // TS2345:
      // Argument of type 'number | null' is not
      // assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
    }
  }

  testWithTyping(this: this & MyType) {
    if (this.isSet) {
      this.logId(this.id); // Works!
    }
  }

  logId(id: number) {
    console.log(id);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TypeScript, classes and interfaces cannot currently be declared to implement union types.  It has been [suggested](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11207), but nothing has happened there yet.  So there's no easy way for the compiler to understand that `MyClass extends MyType` is true.

The two ways I can think of to deal with this involve refactoring your code.  If an instance of `MyClass` is likely to switch back and forth between the two types of `MyType` (e.g., first it's `{isSet: false, id: null}`, and then later it's `{isSet: true, id: 123}`), then I'd recommend making `MyClass` *have* a `MyType` instead of *be* a `MyType`.  This is sort of [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).  Here's how I'd do that:

```
class MyClass {
    myType: MyType = { isSet: false, id: null };

    constructor(id?: number) {
        if (typeof id === 'number' && id > 0) {
            this.myType = { isSet: true, id };
        }
    }

    test() {
        if (this.myType.isSet) {
            this.logId(this.myType.id);
        }
    }
    logId(id: number) {
        console.log(id);
    }
}
```

Note that all references to `this.isSet` or `this.id` were replaced with `this.myType.isSet` and `this.myType.id`.

And you can test it:

```
const s = new MyClass(123);
s.test(); // 123
const u = new MyClass();
u.test(); // nothing
```

---

The other way I'd do it satisfies your original idea that `MyClass` instances actually *are* `MyType`s, but it only works if individual `MyClass` instances will always be either one or the other member of the `MyType` union and do not change.  In this case you can get `MyClass` to be a union of two related classes, like this:

```
abstract class MyClassBase {
    abstract isSet: boolean;
    abstract id: number | null;
    abstract test(): void;
    logId(id: number) {
        console.log(id);
    }
}

class MyClassSet extends MyClassBase implements Extract<MyType, { isSet: true }>{
    readonly isSet = true;
    readonly id: number;
    constructor(id: number) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }
    test() {
        this.logId(this.id);
    }
}

class MyClassUnset extends MyClassBase implements Extract<MyType, { isSet: false }> {
    readonly isSet = false;
    readonly id = null;
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    test() { }
}

type MyClass = MyClassSet | MyClassUnset;
const MyClass = class {
    constructor(id?: number) {
        return (typeof id === 'number' && id > 0) ?
            new MyClassSet(id) : new MyClassUnset();
    }
} as new (id?: number) => MyClass;
```

So both `MyClassSet` and `MyClassUnset` are subclasses of `MyClassBase`, an abstract class in which you'd put all common functionality.  If you need to specify `this: MyType` in method parameters there, it should be fine to do it.  But you probably shouldn't, since any functionality which differs based on whether it's set or unset should be implemented in the corresponding subclass.

Then the `MyClass` type is the union of `MyClassSet` and `MyClassUnset`, and you can even make a `MyClass` constructor that returns a `MyClass`.

The test behaves the same as before:

```
const s = new MyClass(123);
s.test(); // 123
const u = new MyClass();
u.test(); // nothing
```

---

I'd usually prefer the first solution where `MyClass` holds a property of type `MyType` instead of tries to implement `MyType`, because it's more straightforward.  But sometimes class hierarchies are useful, too.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=33&ssc=1&pln=75&pc=1#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAJA9gGwCYQE5IG8AoJUpAFwE8ZkBZSgFWuQF5CkBLKAZQnIC4kAMxAYoEADScsg4AFcMGJAF8kAH3ZdeAirjmTpsuWABGeFQG4iJMvAwgoUJPQDC9x4RtkyYRs0H0TDRIbAScPHyCImIGHDJI8oqW1t7e8GjAUOR68ORouAAUcQD8RqZ4AJSeqTWcQkgFVDRo9XEhLGwA5PLluJ1IAGQD0kgAfEgADFXEtbMUABZcAHS+QayaETrZ+lJtylZzZMpeqccn3uTQ5AXT57Uc9Y2LUCt+NEtafLeHNeTPSxg0ABzACSWCey1WzA+WAqBx+x1miNqgNB4LiZTMuG+P3SmUwEABwKKsPhNWRpDOaQyWSQTjYwAgAHdnJQ3A4oAUAIwAJgAzHCTi9LlkbhYkAB6CVIXl8k542lyEIJZms9mOMUnORLEXXOGS6XANB-DjAIHWM6gSCwBDIFAcPAgXDweaUapkJp0N7rMKfHTRcS7eKJJSqDS+zaCbaxYPGLHJE4gExZXAIchIOwctXuKAAIQcyBmtSTKbT4W0ghMaAJIGAZNSJeyZYxCTj5g0Ifr3kbqdyFCuN0EADc0HEu2RUWCSZjKu7DgqCUSgSTBUiTlTbDnsxztEgIAAPS7ALBOVw5-PiThgGAYCCQYDkJwAUUPvfIAB5AswpBGK7p9CooxFjUuAQCAWAZBgbp+sq0bjqQoHgZB0Gxr08EZjS2y5Pk06tr0OKHFAcg0IUq4-CaLxtGwY53JStH9qKBFzBRS5TixcRkeS64pJuWZnhyACqmR8Huh4QMep5sueBZXjed7iY+SAvk2uSft6P7lpEwiiJeyjjMBqSIRBwBQZp6ZsAGEDoUZyEjAyCgYOhCpYXkpFznMREkZqa6zLqNzsBSKg8aQnrbh4bD8Y4u4aJFUBCeI5D1s5YX0hmW4GdSmQuThJQzti7mzKB5ByLgwANJ6LR2R0SDdG2fSDMMbTjFMSDFPRsyMiysXaCuSCyKqsXxXw3m1IFqgOCqLIkqUeFYlULDjLFVjyphdLKp1KXcvynF0jqA76lKMr8itWVIEqDIDVJHIjaQ2p+QdhrGosZoWkAA)